# CSS 3 column layout with 2 fixed columns and 1 main center column

Tags: css

I have this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fgzgeg68/1/

With the following code HTML:

```
<div class="testContainter">
  <div class="leftPart">
    Short Fixed width Text
  </div>
  <div class="middlePart">
    The long text here should responsivley wrap within this div, and not wrap the div itself onto a new line.
  </div>
  <div class="rightPart">
    Short Fixed width Text
  </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
   .testContainter 
   {
      position: relative;
   }
  .leftPart {
    width : 150px;
    float: left; 
    border : 1px solid red;
  }
  .middlePart {    
    float: left;
    border : 1px solid green;
  }
  .rightPart {
    width : 150px;
    float: right;
    border : 1px solid blue;
  }
```

What I would like to achieve is for the center div not to wrap onto a new line, instead it needs to shrink or grow in width as a "center" column, and the text inside it should wrap.
Thanx.

Comment: is it what you want?: https://jsfiddle.net/tfquy9x1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
.middlePart {
  width : calc(100% - 306px);
  float: left;
  border : 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanx.

Comment: @Breaker - Glad to help! :)

Answer (score -1):

Finally I understood, what do you want to get (at least, I hope):

```
  .testContainter {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .leftPart {
    width : 150px;
    float: left;
    border : 1px solid red;
  }
  .middlePart {    
    display:inline-block;
    border : 1px solid green;
    max-width: 700px;

  }
  .rightPart {
    width : 150px;
    float: right;
    border : 1px solid blue;
  }
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/topxpyza/)